# Centos 6 log errors, how to fix?

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, centos-6, httpd

So for some reason all my images on my blog disappear, no idea why now, but the first time it happened I removed Varnish, and the images came back, everything worked fine. An hour later the images disappear. This time I reboot apache and change the documentroot instead of zpanel, which I removed already. I then restarted apache and the images came back.

Well again, an hour later the images disappear! The images return a 403 forbidden or just forbidden when you visit them directly.

I cleared my error log and when visiting the error log.

```
[Sat Nov 09 08:44:40 2013] [crit] [client 108.162.246.216] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/travisingram.net/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

Really starting to rage badly because nothing is working to fix it, and I can't find anybody else having my issue at ALL.

Help would be EXTREMELY appreciated.

My site: http://travisingram.net/

I am running CentOs 6 with latest lamp setup.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.htaccess` file permissions:

```
ls -la /var/www/travisingram.net/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013
```

Maybe, it doesn't have read permissions. Try:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /var/www/travisingram.net/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013/.htaccess
```

And checkout.